# How to play wmv3 videos

Tags: video, multimedia, codecs

Is there any way to play wmv3 videos on Ubuntu? Tried using VLC player but it says it cannot play the video and there is no way to fix this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Medibuntu** (*Multimedia, Entertainment & Distractions In Ubuntu*) is a repository of packages that cannot be included into the Ubuntu distribution for legal reasons (copyright, license, patent, etc).

Some of these packages include the libdvdcss package from VideoLAN and the external binary codecs package (commonly known as w32codecs) used by MPlayer and xine.

follow this ubuntu guide : [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Medibuntu)

Comment: Note to other users: I found this works with MPlayer but not vlc though.

Answer (score 0):

[This tutorial](http://news.softpedia.com/news/How-to-Install-Multimedia-Codecs-in-Linux-39555.shtml) shows you, how to do that, because it provides a:

> native decoder for Windows Media Video 7/8 (WMV1/WMV2), and Win32 DLL decoder for Windows Media Video 9 (**WMV3**), both used in .wmv files