# WMV files not playing anymore with VLC nor with Video application in 14.04

Tags: 14.04, nautilus, video, vlc, ffmpeg

For an unknown reason, my WMV files are not played with VLC nor with Video application.
VLC or Video application start but disappear instantly.

All those WMV files were readable PERFECTLY via VLC before.

The last thing I remember to have done is installing ffmpeg.

I found the following articles related to problems encountered playing WMV files but none give me the answer to my problem :

[How to play WMV files](https://askubuntu.com/questions/185490/how-to-play-wmv-files)

and [problem playing wmv file under 14.04](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2232866)

I give you the results I have with one test file (copied from a file which was correctly played before) :

```
avconv -i test.wmv
ffmpeg version 1.2.6-7:1.2.6-1~trusty1 Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Apr 26 2014 18:52:58 with gcc 4.8 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1)
  configuration: --arch=amd64 --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --enable-pthreads --enable-runtime-cpudetect --extra-version='7:1.2.6-1~trusty1' --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --prefix=/usr --enable-bzlib --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libfreetype --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-librtmp --enable-libopencv --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-vaapi --enable-vdpau --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-zlib --enable-gpl --enable-postproc --enable-libcdio --enable-x11grab --enable-libx264 --shlibdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --enable-shared --disable-static
  libavutil      52. 18.100 / 52. 18.100
  libavcodec     54. 92.100 / 54. 92.100
  libavformat    54. 63.104 / 54. 63.104
  libavdevice    53.  5.103 / 53.  5.103
  libavfilter     3. 42.103 /  3. 42.103
  libswscale      2.  2.100 /  2.  2.100
  libswresample   0. 17.102 /  0. 17.102
  libpostproc    52.  2.100 / 52.  2.100
[wmv3 @ 0x16d5980] Extra data: 8 bits left, value: 0
Guessed Channel Layout for  Input Stream #0.0 : stereo
Input #0, asf, from 'test.wmv':
  Metadata:
    WMFSDKNeeded    : 0.0.0.0000
    DeviceConformanceTemplate: MP@HL
    WMFSDKVersion   : 11.0.5721.5265
    IsVBR           : 0
  Duration: 00:32:44.20, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 2106 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Audio: wmav2 (a[1][0][0] / 0x0161), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 96 kb/s
    Stream #0:1(eng): Video: wmv3 (Main) (WMV3 / 0x33564D57), yuv420p, 850x480, 2000 kb/s, 29.97 tbr, 1k tbn, 1k tbc
At least one output file must be specified
laurent06000@PC-DE-LDP:/run/user/1000/gvfs/smb-share:server=wdmycloud3,share=laurent06000/Torrents$ 



vlc -vvv
VLC media player 2.1.6 Rincewind (revision 2.1.4+git20150124+r54591+19+11~ubuntu14.04.1)
[0xc1f118] main libvlc debug: VLC media player - 2.1.6 Rincewind
[0xc1f118] main libvlc debug: Copyright © 1996-2015 the VideoLAN team
[0xc1f118] main libvlc debug: revision 2.1.4+git20150124+r54591+19+11~ubuntu14.04.1
[0xc1f118] main libvlc debug: configured with ./configure  '--includedir=${prefix}/include' '--mandir=${prefix}/share/man' '--infodir=${prefix}/share/info' '--localstatedir=/var' '--libdir=${prefix}/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu' '--libexecdir=${prefix}/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu' '--disable-dependency-tracking' '--build=x86_64-linux-gnu' 'CPPFLAGS=-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2' 'LDFLAGS=-Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro' '--config-cache' '--disable-maintainer-mode' '--disable-silent-rules' '--disable-update-check' '--enable-fast-install' '--prefix=/usr' '--docdir=/usr/share/doc/vlc-nox' '--libdir=/usr/lib' '--sysconfdir=/etc' '--with-binary-version=' '--enable-a52' '--enable-aa' '--enable-bluray' '--enable-bonjour' '--enable-caca' '--enable-chromaprint' '--enable-dbus' '--enable-dca' '--enable-dirac' '--enable-directfb' '--enable-dvbpsi' '--enable-dvdnav' '--enable-faad' '--enable-flac' '--enable-fluidsynth' '--enable-freetype' '--enable-fribidi' '--enable-gnutls' '--enable-jack' '--enable-kate' '--enable-libass' '--enable-libfreerdp' '--enable-libmpeg2' '--enable-libxml2' '--enable-lirc' '--enable-live555' '--enable-mad' '--enable-mkv' '--enable-mod' '--enable-mpc' '--enable-mtp' '--enable-mux_ogg' '--enable-ncurses' '--enable-notify' '--enable-ogg' '--enable-opus' '--enable-oss' '--enable-pulse' '--enable-qt' '--enable-realrtsp' '--enable-samplerate' '--enable-schroedinger' '--enable-sdl' '--enable-sftp' '--enable-shout' '--enable-skins2' '--enable-smbclient' '--enable-speex' '--enable-svg' '--enable-taglib' '--enable-theora' '--enable-twolame' '--enable-upnp' '--enable-vcd' '--enable-vcdx' '--enable-vorbis' '--enable-x264' '--enable-zvbi' '--with-kde-solid=/usr/share/kde4/apps/solid/actions/' '--disable-decklink' '--disable-dxva2' '--disable-fdkaac' '--disable-gnomevfs' '--disable-goom' '--disable-libvnc' '--disable-opencv' '--disable-projectm' '--disable-quicksync' '--disable-sndio' '--disable-telx' '--disable-vsxu' '--disable-wasapi' '--enable-alsa' '--enable-atmo' '--enable-dc1394' '--enable-dv1394' '--enable-linsys' '--enable-omxil' '--enable-udev' '--enable-libva' '--enable-v4l2' '--enable-crystalhd' '--enable-mmx' '--enable-sse' '--disable-neon' '--disable-altivec' 'CFLAGS=-g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security' 'CXXFLAGS=-g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security' 'build_alias=x86_64-linux-gnu'
[0xc1f118] main libvlc debug: searching plug-in modules
[0xc1f118] main libvlc debug: loading plugins cache file /usr/lib/vlc/plugins/plugins.dat
[0xc1f118] main libvlc debug: recursively browsing `/usr/lib/vlc/plugins'
[0xc1f118] main libvlc debug: saving plugins cache /usr/lib/vlc/plugins/plugins.dat
[0xc1f118] main libvlc debug: plug-ins loaded: 426 modules
[0xc1f118] main libvlc debug: opening config file (/home/laurent06000/.config/vlc/vlcrc)
[0xc1f118] main libvlc debug: translation test: code is "fr"
[0xc1f118] main libvlc debug: CPU has capabilities MMX MMXEXT SSE SSE2 SSE3 SSSE3 SSE4.1 SSE4.2 FPU 
[0xc33c18] main input debug: Creating an input for 'Bibliothèque'
[0xc33c18] main input debug: Input is a meta file: disabling unneeded options
[0xc33c18] main input debug: using timeshift granularity of 50 MiB, in path '/tmp'
[0xc33c18] main input debug: `file/xspf-open:///home/laurent06000/.local/share/vlc/ml.xspf' gives access `file' demux `xspf-open' path `/home/laurent06000/.local/share/vlc/ml.xspf'
[0xc33c18] main input debug: creating demux: access='file' demux='xspf-open' location='/home/laurent06000/.local/share/vlc/ml.xspf' file='/home/laurent06000/.local/share/vlc/ml.xspf'
[0xe2af28] main demux debug: looking for access_demux module matching "file": 20 candidates
[0xe2af28] main demux debug: no access_demux modules matched
[0xc33c18] main input debug: creating access 'file' location='/home/laurent06000/.local/share/vlc/ml.xspf', path='/home/laurent06000/.local/share/vlc/ml.xspf'
[0xc38d48] main access debug: looking for access module matching "file": 25 candidates
[0xc38d48] filesystem access debug: opening file `/home/laurent06000/.local/share/vlc/ml.xspf'
[0xc38d48] main access debug: using access module "filesystem"
[0xc39a88] main stream debug: Using stream method for AStream*
[0xc39a88] main stream debug: starting pre-buffering
[0xc39a88] main stream debug: received first data after 0 ms
[0xc39a88] main stream debug: pre-buffering done 296 bytes in 0s - 20647 KiB/s
[0xc39ce8] main stream debug: looking for stream_filter module matching "any": 9 candidates
[0xc39ce8] main stream debug: no stream_filter modules matched
[0xc39ce8] main stream debug: looking for stream_filter module matching "record": 9 candidates
[0xc39ce8] main stream debug: using stream_filter module "record"
[0xc33c18] main input debug: creating demux: access='file' demux='xspf-open' location='/home/laurent06000/.local/share/vlc/ml.xspf' file='/home/laurent06000/.local/share/vlc/ml.xspf'
[0xc3c9e8] main demux debug: looking for demux module matching "xspf-open": 63 candidates
[0xc3c9e8] playlist demux debug: using XSPF playlist reader
[0xc3c9e8] main demux debug: using demux module "playlist"
[0xc3cc78] main demux meta debug: looking for meta reader module matching "any": 2 candidates
[0xc3cc78] lua demux meta debug: Trying Lua scripts in /home/laurent06000/.local/share/vlc/lua/meta/reader
[0xc3cc78] lua demux meta debug: Trying Lua scripts in /usr/lib/vlc/lua/meta/reader
[0xc3cc78] lua demux meta debug: Trying Lua playlist script /usr/lib/vlc/lua/meta/reader/filename.luac
[0xc3cc78] lua demux meta debug: Trying Lua scripts in /usr/share/vlc/lua/meta/reader
[0xc3cc78] main demux meta debug: no meta reader modules matched
[0xc33c18] main input debug: `file/xspf-open:///home/laurent06000/.local/share/vlc/ml.xspf' successfully opened
[0xceed98] main xml reader debug: looking for xml reader module matching "any": 1 candidates
[0xceed98] main xml reader debug: using xml reader module "xml"
[0xc3c9e8] playlist demux debug: parsed 0 tracks successfully
[0xc33c18] main input debug: EOF reached
[0xc3c9e8] main demux debug: removing module "playlist"
[0xc39ce8] main stream debug: removing module "record"
[0xc38d48] main access debug: removing module "filesystem"
[0xe13e98] main playlist debug: creating audio output
[0xc39a88] main audio output debug: looking for audio output module matching "any": 6 candidates
[0xc39a88] pulse audio output debug: using library version 4.0.0
[0xc39a88] pulse audio output debug:  (compiled with version 4.0.0, protocol 28)
[0xc39a88] pulse audio output debug: connected locally to unix:/run/user/1000/pulse/native as client #12
[0xc39a88] pulse audio output debug: using protocol 28, server protocol 28
[0xc39a88] main audio output debug: using audio output module "pulse"
[0xc39a88] pulse audio output debug: adding sink 0: alsa_output.pci-0000_01_00.1.hdmi-stereo (Juniper HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 5700 Series] Digital Stereo (HDMI))
[0xe13e98] main playlist debug: keeping audio output
[0xc39a88] pulse audio output debug: adding sink 1: alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo (Audio interne Stéréo analogique)
[0xc4ad98] main interface debug: looking for interface module matching "hotkeys,none": 19 candidates
[0xc4ad98] main interface debug: using interface module "hotkeys"
[0xc4b748] main interface debug: looking for interface module matching "globalhotkeys,none": 19 candidates
[0xc4b748] main interface debug: using interface module "globalhotkeys"
[0xcf4ba8] main interface debug: looking for interface module matching "dbus,none": 19 candidates
[0xcf4ba8] dbus interface debug: listening on dbus as: org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.vlc.instance4929
[0xcf4ba8] main interface debug: using interface module "dbus"
[0xc1f118] main libvlc: Lancement de vlc avec l'interface par défaut. Utilisez « cvlc » pour démarrer VLC sans interface.
[0xc4e4a8] main interface debug: looking for interface module matching "any": 19 candidates
[0xcf4ba8] dbus interface debug: Getting All properties
[0xcf4ba8] dbus interface debug: Getting All properties
[0xcf4ba8] dbus interface debug: Getting All properties
[0x7f3a284748c8] main generic debug: looking for extension module matching "any": 1 candidates
[0x7f3a284748c8] lua generic debug: Opening Lua Extension module
[0x7f3a284748c8] lua generic debug: Trying Lua scripts in /home/laurent06000/.local/share/vlc/lua/extensions
[0x7f3a284748c8] lua generic debug: Trying Lua scripts in /usr/lib/vlc/lua/extensions
[0x7f3a284748c8] lua generic debug: Trying Lua playlist script /usr/lib/vlc/lua/extensions/VLSub.luac
[0x7f3a284748c8] lua generic debug: Scanning Lua script /usr/lib/vlc/lua/extensions/VLSub.luac
[0x7f3a284748c8] lua generic debug: Script /usr/lib/vlc/lua/extensions/VLSub.luac has the following capability flags: 0x5
[0x7f3a284748c8] lua generic debug: Trying Lua scripts in /usr/share/vlc/lua/extensions
[0x7f3a284748c8] main generic debug: using extension module "lua"
[0xc4e4a8] main interface debug: using interface module "qt4"
[0xc1f118] main libvlc debug: exiting
[0xc1f118] main libvlc debug: removing all interfaces
[0xc1f118] main libvlc debug: exiting
[0xc4e4a8] main interface debug: removing module "qt4"
[0xe13e98] main playlist debug: deactivating the playlist
[0xc39a88] main audio output debug: removing module "pulse"
[0xc4e4a8] qt4 interface debug: requesting exit...
[0xc4e4a8] qt4 interface debug: waiting for UI thread...
[0xc4e4a8] qt4 interface debug: QApp exec() finished
[0xc4e4a8] qt4 interface debug: Video is not needed anymore
[0xc4e4a8] qt4 interface debug: Killing extension dialog provider
[0xc4e4a8] qt4 interface debug: ExtensionsDialogProvider is quitting...
[0x7f3a284748c8] main generic debug: removing module "lua"
[0x7f3a284748c8] lua generic debug: Deactivating all loaded extensions
[0x7f3a284748c8] lua generic debug: All extensions are now deactivated
[0xcf4ba8] main interface debug: removing module "dbus"
[0xc4b748] main interface debug: removing module "globalhotkeys"
[0xc4ad98] main interface debug: removing module "hotkeys"
[0xe13e98] main playlist debug: destroying
[0xc4e868] main playlist export debug: saving Bibliothèque to file /home/laurent06000/.local/share/vlc/ml.xspf
[0xc4e868] main playlist export debug: looking for playlist export module matching "export-xspf": 4 candidates
[0xc4e868] main playlist export debug: using playlist export module "export"
[0xc4e868] main playlist export debug: removing module "export"
[0xc1f118] main libvlc debug: removing stats
laurent06000@PC-DE-LDP:/run/user/1000/gvfs/smb-share:server=wdmycloud3,share=laurent06000/Torrents$
```

I tried to uninstall / reinstall ffmpeg and VLC, rebooting the PC with no positive result.

Any idea would be welcome.

IMPORTANT NOTE :

I also noticed that in Nautilus when I try to see the properties of ANY WMV file, nautilus closes ALL opened Tabs (????). This problem daos not affect MP4 files.

Answer (score 1):

I've found the answer. To be sincere I do not remember the internet link where to find this answer.

In `.config/vlc` just put this file replacing `vlc-qt-interface.conf` :

[vlc-qt-interface.conf file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/4t74ghmk7wdzps0/vlc-qt-interface.conf?dl=0)

Then in the file named `~/.config/vlc/vlcrc` copy the following :

```
[qt4] # Qt interface
qt-privacy-ask=0
[schroedinger] # Dirac video decoder using libschroedinger
sout-schro-rate-control=constant_noise_threshold
sout-schro-gop-structure=adaptive
sout-schro-mv-precision=1
sout-schro-motion-block-size=automatic
sout-schro-motion-block-overlap=automatic
sout-schro-intra-wavelet=desl_dubuc_9_7
sout-schro-inter-wavelet=desl_dubuc_9_7
sout-schro-codeblock-size=automatic
sout-schro-filtering=none
sout-schro-perceptual-weighting=none
sout-schro-force-profile=auto
[rtp] # Real-Time Protocol (RTP) input
rtp-dynamic-pt=theora
[filesystem] # File input
ignore-filetypes=m3u,db,nfo,ini,jpg,jpeg,ljpg,gif,png,pgm,pgmyuv,pbm,pam,tga,bmp,pnm,xpm,xcf,pcx,tif,tiff,lbm,sfv,txt,sub,idx,srt,cue,ssa,zip,rar
[dtv] # Digital Television and Radio
dvb-transmission=-1
[mono] # Audio filter for stereo to mono conversion
sout-mono-channel=0
[compressor] # Compression dynamique
compressor-attack=1.500000
compressor-release=2.000000
compressor-threshold=0.000000
compressor-ratio=1.000000
compressor-knee=1.000000
compressor-makeup-gain=0.000000
[param_eq] # Parametric Equalizer
[equalizer] # Equalizer with 10 bands
equalizer-preamp=0.000000
[main] # main program
deinterlace=-1
sub-autodetect-file=0
random=1
repeat=1
one-instance-when-started-from-file=0
album-art=2
hotkeys-mousewheel-mode=1
extrashort-jump-size=15
short-jump-size=30
```

PS : I hope the files will be accessible : I've made a link from personal dropbox files (please tell me if you cannot have access those 2 files too large to copy contents here....

Comment: Hi, I've downloaded vlcrc and extract from them the active settings (removing all comment lines starting with `#`)