# How to open this strange wmv (wmv3) movie in Ubuntu?

Tags: codecs, wmv

I could see there are some new movies with wmv file format, but on my Ubuntu 15.10 nothing seems to be able to play these files. I tried SMPlayer, it shows some strange image, no sound; VLC crashes the system, creates few GB of swap; Totem player crashes in the beginning ("The stream is encrypted and decryption is not supported").

I uploaded the file on my Dropbox account, here (the Download is on the upper right side): 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/fle5634rg5gmlv7/11.22.63%20S01E08%202015%20HDTV%20x264%20-%20AFG.wmv?dl=0

Maybe some more experienced one can have a look at it.

There is a chance the file could be corrupted, but it happens the same with many extremely new movies having this format and thousands of people share them, I would think they would say something if this is a bad joke.

I have no idea what to do to open this file (and similar ones), but I do have ubuntu-restricted-extras installed and I could find no other movie not be played on my system. And it is a quite capable one, performance should not be an issue.

Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to play WMV files?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/185490/how-to-play-wmv-files)

Answer (score 4):

This file is encumbered with Digital Rights Management (DRM) and thus cannot be played on Ubuntu.

1. MPlayer reports:

   ```
   DRM License URL: http://www.microsoft.com/isapi/redir.dll?prd=wmdrm&pver=2&os=win&sbp=newclient
   This file has been encumbered with DRM encryption, it will not play in MPlayer!
   ```
2. And mediainfo has the same story:

   ```
   [...]
   Encryption                               : http://www.microsoft.com/isapi/redir.dll?prd=wmdrm&pver=2&os=win&sbp=newclient
   Encoded date                             : UTC 2016-02-11 00:07:28.422
   MediaFoundationVersion                   : 2.112
   [...]
   Language                                 : English (US)
   Encryption                               : Encrypted
   ```
3. ffprobe shows:

   ```
   [asf @ 0x655d00] Ext DRM protected stream detected, decoding will likely fail!
   [asf @ 0x655d00] DRM protected stream detected, decoding will likely fail!
   ```

Unfortunately this leaves your file completely unplayable under Linux....